# Line integral over the intersection of a sphere with a cylinder

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, line-integrals

I really do not know how to solve this one. I did a lot of research on the internet and could not find an answer.

> Find the work done by moving a particle over $C$, where $C$ is the
>   intersection of the upper hemisphere $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = a^2$ with the
>   cylinder $x^2 + y^2 = ax$ , $a>0$. Force field is $F = (y,z,x)$

My main problem is that I can't really picture $C$.
Any help is appreciated. If it can be solved with Stoke's Theorem as well I would like to see that answer too.

Answer (score 0):

The intersection is a tear shaped curve $C$.

[image]
([Large Version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSkqV.png))

Have a look at this interactive GeoGebra worksheet here: [link](https://ggbm.at/kjG2NSqx)

You might move around the circle of the cylinder with center at $(a/2, 0, 0)$ and radius $a/2$, and adjust the height according to the sphere:
\begin{align}
x(t) &= a/2 + (a/2) \cos t \\
y(t) &= (a/2) \sin t \\
z(t) &= \sqrt{a^2 - (x(t)^2 + y(t)^2)}
\end{align}